# Check length of Object size / BootstrapVue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, size, bootstrap-vue

I've updated my code - I think before it was not clear enough.

I try to write in my number and get my input in the other two fields **but** only when its correct otherwise my input fields should include informatione "false number", but it's not working..

also when I input 3 numbers and they are in my json file it gives console.log "Not in file" - but it is..

Hope now someone can help me out..

```
<template>
<div>
  <div class='inputArea mt-2' v-for='(element, index) in inputs' :key='index'>
    <b-button v-b-toggle="'newElement'+index" variant='secondary btn-block'>Element {{index+1}}</b-button>

    <b-collapse :id="'newElement'+index">
      <div class='m-2 mt-3'>
        <table class='table table-striped mt-2'>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-6 m-1'>
                  <div class='mt-2'>Input Number</div>
                  <b-form-input v-model="element.Number" @input="searchelementInformations(element.Number)"></b-form-input>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-5 ml-1 mr-1'>
                  <div class='mt-2'>Autofill 1</div>
                  <b-form-input :value="element.Autofill1" ></b-form-input>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-5 ml-1 mr-1'>
                  <div class='mt-2'>Autofill 2</div>
                  <b-form-input :value="element.Autofill2"></b-form-input>
                </div>

              </div>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </b-collapse>
    </div>

    <div class='mt-4 mb-5 ml-3 mr-3'>
      <b-button @click='addelement' variant='block' type='button'>Add Element</b-button>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>


<script>

export default {
  methods: {
    addelement() {
      this.inputs.push ({
      });
    }, 

    searchelementInformations(inputNumber) {

      var size = Object.keys(inputNumber).length;
      console.log(size);

      this.jsonAutofill.forEach(element => {
        if ((size === 3) && (+element.Number === +inputNumber)) {
          for(const key of Object.keys(element)) {
            inputNumber = element[key];
            console.log(key);
            console.log(inputNumber);
          }
        }
        else if (size !== 3) {
          console.log("Not correct length");
        }
        else if ((size === 3) && (+element.Number !== +inputNumber)){
          console.log("Not in file")
        }
      });       
    }, 
  },

  data() {
      return {
        inputs:[{}],
        Artikelnummer: [],
        jsonAutofill: [
          { "Number": 123, "Autofill1": "Test1", "Autofill2": "Hello"},
          { "Number": 321, "Autofill1": "Test2", "Autofill2": "Goodbye"},
        ],
      }
  }
};
</script>


<style scoped>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer.. I need to reference "Number" in my Object.keys than I will get the length.

```
var size = Object.keys(inputNumber.Number).length;
      console.log(size);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would watch for the reactive data, [like this](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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):

```html
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      number: 0,
      message: ""
    }
  },
  watch: {
    "number"(){
      if (this.number.length == 5) {
        this.message = "Do this"
      }
      else {
        this.message = "Do that"
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="number">
  <div>{{ message }}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: hey, i think it was not really clear enough what i meant. I've copied in my complete code for this - hopefully it's better now to understand what i need. Thanks for your help !